# VueRouter 4: navigation aboorted in Chromium on back/forward

Tags: vue-router

When I click back/forward buttons in Chromium (not Chrome), vue router gives me the error:

```
"Error: Navigation aborted from "/ORG/studies/STUDY-2324/edit" to "/ORG/studies/STUDY-2324/cohort/0" via a navigation guard.
    at createRouterError (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-router.js?v=81cba8c3:558:19)
    at next (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-router.js?v=81cba8c3:1320:16)
    at http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-router.js?v=81cba8c3:1373:12
    at http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-NHNZTCC3.js?v=81cba8c3:4324:11
    at http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-EXT4546V.js?v=81cba8c3:456:20
    at http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-router.js?v=81cba8c3:1339:31
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-router.js?v=81cba8c3:1317:16
    at Object.runWithContext (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-J6475X5X.js?v=81cba8c3:5256:18)
    at runWithContext (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-router.js?v=81cba8c3:2332:66)"
```

Looks like internal bug, but I have no idea how to reproduce it. Everything works fine in Chrome. My router configuration is also pretty default, no navigation guards (no beforeEnter/beforeEach).

Comment: Could you please include all your router code? Or, preferably, a [reduced version that still demonstrates the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That would let us test with an already-made router config that doesn't work, instead of having to recreate it ourselves.

Comment: In _addition_, a reproduction in something like StackBlitz would be useful (or a GitHub repo).